# recursion and operator ||

Tags: javascript, recursion

everyone!

Please help me to understand some steps of the program execution.The essence of the program is that we have an initial number, for example number 13, and using recursion we create an expression as (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5). This program is from the textbook and there is no error in it.

Somewhere in the middle of the program there comes a point where null || null and after this point the IDE starts to do steps I don't understand.

Here's the function code

```js
function findSolution(target)
{
    function find(current, history) // 1 "1" // 6 "(1 + 5)" // 11 "((1 + 5) + 5)" // 16 NULL
                                   // 33 "((1 + 5) + 5)" NULL
    {
        console.log(current, history);
        if(current == target)
        {
            return history;
        }
        else if(current > target)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {

            return find(current + 5,`(${history} + 5)`) ||
                   find(current * 3,`(${history} * 3)`);
        }
    }
    
    return find(1, "1");
}


console.log(findSolution(13));
```

[image]

After that the current: 6 history "(1+5)" appears. Where did it come from? After all, it needed to enter recursion, but then how could it terminate if current = 6?

[image]

Sorry for such a long message, but I am a newbie and do not know how to explain problems intelligently yet.

Comment: it is an exit condition to end the recursion. maybe you have a look to [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) and its result with taking [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: I still didn't get the problem

Comment: Now it's clear for me. I just needed to see a real diagram of all calls. Thx for helping me you all!

Comment: @GeKtoRiX you are skating on thin ice if you are a new learner of recursion. You shouldn't look down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following diagram explains your recursive calls tree

- The numbers in blue represent the sequence.
- The conditions in red represent why this call is made.

[image: Recursive calls tree]

Comment: Thank you friend. You are my hero!!! Can you tell me where you can create such trees?